# How to create Random URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

HI!

There are localhost:3000 my application.. but i want to create a link something like this -> localhost:3000/53843 (this is random digit rand(999999)).. How possible i can paste this run into url? and if user enter localhost:3000 he gets an error or redirect to localhost:3000/53843 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I'll assume you have a redirection model that has an ID (53843) and a redirection_path (google).com.

in your routes file, tell it to have :path=>'' -- otherwise it would expect /redirections/53843

```
resources :redirections, :path=>''
```

Then in your controller

```
class RedirectionsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    redirection = Redirection.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to redirection.redirection_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a unique field in your model. When a new object is created, add a method that assigns random string, or number to this field. After that modify routes.rb and controller so that you could return an object by the value of this random field in url.